# How to show several plots with ListAnimate

Tags: animation

I'm having trouble running some animations, I would appreciate some help.

I want to use the `ListAnimate` to show the results of a Monte Carlo simulation, that I have stored in a data file. I'm trying to show two simultaneous animations in a single plot. I have managed to do this by using `Manipulate` and then running the simulation automatically. However, I still feel that that this could be done using `ListAnimate`. Any ideas or suggestions as to how this may be possible?

As an example, the specific code I use in `Manipulate` is:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ListLinePlot[data1[[n]], PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Joined -> True], 
  ListLinePlot[data2[[n]], PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Joined -> True]], {n,
   1, 2, 1}]
```

In this case, the lists have the same number of objects, but they may contain different number of objects, in which case I could just use two variables instead of one, however, running them simultaneously proves to be a problem.

That way I just use the play button on the control options and it runs, that is, it plots both graphs on the same plot and the animation runs. This is fine, however I find that a ListAnimate function would be more suitable for the number of points I have to plot. How could I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Do you mean:  Manipulate[
 Show[ListLinePlot[data1[[n]], PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Joined -> True], 
  ListLinePlot[data2[[n]], PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Joined -> True]], {n,
   1, 2, 1}] ? please review your example code to be syntactically correct, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code using ListAnimate

```
data1 = {{{0, 2}, {1, 4}}, {{0, 2}, {1, 8}}};
data2 = {{{0, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 5}}};
    Show /@ Transpose @  (Table[
       ListLinePlot[#[[n]], PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Joined -> True], {n,
         1, 2, 1}] & /@ {data1, data2}) // ListAnimate
```

ListAnimate animates a sequence of elements in a list by considering them as frames. Therefore all ListLinePlot results need to be generated in a list for being animated.  I would prefer your initial solution using Manipulate, however this is subjective. 
Please  correct your syntax of code in your question. It should be like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ListLinePlot[data1[[n]], PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Joined -> True], 
  ListLinePlot[data2[[n]], PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Joined -> True]], {n,
   1, 2, 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful. :-)